# What is the difference between text-based image retrieval and natural language object retrieval?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language-processing, comparison, object-detection

I'm working on creating a model that locates the object in the scene (2D image or 3D scene) using a natural language query. I came across this paper on [natural language object retrieval](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Hu_Natural_Language_Object_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf), which mentions that this task is different from text-based image retrieval, in the sense that natural language object retrieval requires an understanding of objects in the image, spatial configurations, etc. I am not able to see the difference between these two approaches. Could you please explain it with an example?